# Use multiple smaller varchars vs one big

Tags: mysql, innodb, varchar

(mysql innodb)

Suppose i want to list a recipe description in steps like below. Should i use multiple smaller varchars for each step or should i use one big one? What would you think is the most flexible/efficient?
Keep in mind that im a newbie when it comes to databases. Also, is varchar the right tool for the job?Thanks!

1. Set oven at 350 degrees
2. Add milk
3. Add eggs
4. Bake for 40 minutes

Also, in case it matters for performance/storage the language stored will be swedish (includes a few "weird" characters)

Comment: What's your use case? How will you be accessing these values?

Comment: Good question. I guess the data stored would only be used to output the list above or similar. The ingredients and amounts are stored separately and wont affect the list above.

Answer (score 0):

You would rather use `nvarchar`. The `varchar` has a fixed size no matter how big is your entry. The `nvarchar` is as big as the entry.

Example:
`nvarchar(50)` with entry 'aa' takes up 2 characters
`varchar(50)` with entry 'aa' takes up 50 characters

Comment: Seems useful, i'll look it up. Never heard of it before.

Answer (score 0):

I think recipe description would be one field in database.. right ?

If you can't imagine how long it would be You should keep it text so you can add long text also.

Comment: Yes, it seems logical to me as well. I guess the reason im asking is mostly because i designed it to be multiple varchars before thinking much about it and wanted some input. I'll research text and nvarchar and see what i come up with.